# Switch Default Gateway to Another Router with Different Subnet

Tags: ubuntu, networking

My diagram:

[image]

Currently subnet 192.168.8.0/24 get internet connection from modem A via the Default Gateway 192.168.8.1, my goal is to divert the 192.168.8.0/24 subnet in order to get internet connection from modem A (Gateway 192.168.7.1) when Modem A getting in trouble .

Both Router installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.5

This is what I have done; add default gateway on Router B to Router A

```
$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.7.1
```

Which makes Router B to get an internet connection from modem A but not with the subnet 192.168.8.0/24, what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically added it the problem is almost certainly the lack of a route for `192.168.8.0/24` on router A.  Sure you have a route on B telling traffic how to get out, but router A has no idea how to **route** the traffic back properly until you add a route on router A.

If adding a route on Router A is not an option, the other **ugly** solution is just to setup SNAT so that any traffic leaving router B will appear to router A as coming from router B.